# Is there a method in PL/SQL to convert/encode text to XML compliant text?

Tags: xml, oracle, plsql

I have a colleague who needs to convert text from a PL/SQL method into XML compliant text, as he is constructing a excel spreadsheet by updating a text template.

Is there a method in PL/SQL to convert/encode text to XML compliant text?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Well, if you just want to convert XML characters, you'll want to do something like...

```
  outgoing_text := DBMS_XMLGEN.CONVERT(incoming_text)
```

Where `outgoing_text` and `incoming_text` are both VARCHAR2 or CLOB.

You can specify a second argument, but it defaults to `DBMS_XMLGEN.ENTITY_ENCODE`... it can also decode XML entities by passing `DBMS_XMLGEN.ENTITY_DECODE` as a second argument.

Comment: Thanks that sorted it all apart from a pound symbol which is probably a character set issue somewhere.

Comment: Just to note, this also encodes characters within CDATA elements.

Answer (score 4):

Later versions of oracle have a built in [XML package](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/DBMS_XMLGEN) for manipulating XML data.
For example, is this the sort of thing your colleague wants to do?:

```
SELECT DBMS_XMLGEN.getXML('SELECT * FROM emp') FROM dual;
```

Comment: That's quite useful, as it produces an entire xml fragment, however I was looking for something which converted text into xml without including the enclosing tags.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to dbms_xmlgen, you can use the sql method, xmlelement and then extract the value back out.

```
select extract(xmlelement("mytest",my_variable),'mytest/text()') from dual;
```

The xmlelement function will make the text XML compliant, then using the extract function, it will extract the text out as is.  (Note: The extractValue function will convert the text back to the non-XML compliant version.).

Answer (score 0):

hamischmcn option is easy and clear but it does not work in oracle forms, I tried a lot using that and nothing...you can generate the xml manually, using something like this

utl_file.put_line_nchar (file_id, 'xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"');

utl_file.put_line_nchar (file_id, 'Start');

--A FOR LOOP WHERE YOU DEFINE YOUR TAGS

utl_file.put_line_nchar (file_id, '/Start');

**Note: Editor does not allow me to put the < > signs in the xml and tags title**

Comment: Thanks, but i'm looking at something which will encode text i.e. convert characters into their xml compliant characters.

Answer (score 0):

With respect to Rulas's issue on Oracle Forms, there are a lot of things Forms can't do (in various versions), where you need to use a database package.

So write a database PL/SQL function that does the dbms_xmlgen and return a varchar2 or clob, depending on the size of your XML. Then you can call that function from Forms. when you get the data back into Forms, use text_io or webutil to push the XML file to Excel.

Or stay over on the database side and use utl_file to push the XML output to a directory where you can get at it.