# How to delete all invalid xml characters?

Tags: xml, oracle, plsql

I have a clob file with data stored in svg format. Then I have a tool that generates pdf file from this svg. When 
I generate pdf I get an error:

> "An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0x12) was found in the element content of the document".

I tried to replace all conrol and other characters using

```
regexp_replace(text, '( *[[:cntrl:]])', '');
regexp_replace(text, '( *[[:punct:]])', '');
```

but i still have this error. What can I do to solve this problem using pl/sql?

Comment: Instead of removing the invalid characters, you could try to encode them.  Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/461970/is-there-a-method-in-pl-sql-to-convert-encode-text-to-xml-compliant-text

Comment: You need to understand why the input contains those characters. Just  removing them is likely to break things further down the line.  You have provided very little detail for anybody to help you.  You might start by providing a sample SVG file that demonstrates the problem and, tell us which SVG-to-PDF tool you are using.

Comment: This svg [**file**](https://github.com/adelak/Files/blob/master/test.svg)
returns: 

An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0x1d) was found in the element content of the document.